# How to find visible class based on partial id and then return full id in jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I find the visible class based on partial id and then return the full id in jquery, here is some of my code for you to get a better understanding.

```
<div class="visible" id="fares-and-payments-1-10kms">
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="fares-and-payments-11-20kms">
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="fares-and-payments-21-30kms">
</div>
```

So basically if you take the snippet above I want to return the "fares-and-payments-1-10kms" id as that is the div that has a class that is visible.

The most elegant and efficient way would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the attribute starts-with selector, in combination with the class

```
var elem = $('[id^="fares-and-payments"].visible');
```

That gets you the element, if you need the ID, you'd just do `elem.prop('id')`

Comment: you're a star, and saved me a lot of head scratching Lol.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ Here is some documentation to the attribute starts-with selector.

Comment: Thanks very much @Atlas.

Comment: I also checked out [http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) after having a look at [http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector), notes the $ for the ends with instead of the ^ for starts with.